# UITabbar + ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios4, modalviewcontroller, tabbar

I have a viewController that I am presenting as modalViewController in my ParentViewController. The parentViewController has a UITab bar with 2 tabs. When I present the ChildCiewController as modalViewController, there is blank space the size of UITab bar at the bottom of the ChildViewController.view. How to get rid of it?

```
InAppPurchaseViewController *purchaseViewController = [[InAppPurchaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InAppPurchaseViewController" bundle:nil];              


purchaseViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;                      

[self presentModalViewController:purchaseViewController animated:YES];

[purchaseViewController release];
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that purchaseViewController.view.frame is correct (0, 0, 320, 480).

Test with 
CGRect r = purchaseViewController.view.frame;
NSLog(@"frame is: %d - %d - %d -%d", r.origin.x, r.origin.y, r.size.width, r.size.height)

Hope this helps

Comment: I got it. My frame was not set properly.